# Cannot find module 'url' though I installed globally

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I installed url module with npm install -g url

But I get error Cannot find module 'url'  when executing this phantomjs script

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();

    var system = require('system');
    var args = system.args;

    const Url = require('url');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS is not in any way related to node.js. It has a separate execution environment and doesn't load global npm modules. However, it can load locally installed npm modules provided that they do not use any functionality that node.js has but PhantomJS does not.

Comment: Thanks, I just did npm install url then my script works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NodeJS package which merged the use of PhantomJS inside Node.JS.

```
npm install after-load
```

This  package  is called `after-load` which runs PhantomJS script using shell command line wrapped by Node.JS .

### Expamle of Use :

```
afterLoad('http://cv.abdennoor.com',function(html,$){
  console.log(
     $('title').html()
  )
});
```

Comment: You always need to disclose if you're related to the project/library/framework you're recommending. A simple *"my"* would be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will try it.